# .htaccess friendly url rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 categories in my website one is CONTRY and the other one is TOWN. 
Now the non-friendly URL looks something like this:

1. mywebsite.com/country.php?url=clients-in-england (for country category)
2. mywebsite.com/town.php?url=clients-in-london (for town category)

Now i want those nonfriendly url's to be something like this:

1. mywebsite.com/clients-in-england
2. mywebsite.com/clients-in-london

How can i exactly do this using .htaccess
My current htaccess code is below:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(country|town)\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(country|town)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I don't want any folder just simply mywebsite.com/clients-in-england

Comment: You wrote: `mywebsite.com/country/clients-in-england` in question

Comment: My bad, sorry. I want to say mywebsite.com/clients-in-england

Comment: But after edit your question became invalid as `/abcd` cannot be routed to all `country.php` and `city.php` and `page.php`. You must keep a path before city/country name as previous question.

Comment: Understand. Thank you for your reply.